# Angular Html not waiting for my controlers to finish loading

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Again I am struggling with an Angular problem. in my TS file, I am calling 3 API's to bring me data based on a specific selected user, and I am merging all of them into an object to display them unified in the interface, however, my HTML page doesn't wait for the object to finish building and it's showing massive error.

This is my typescript code:

```js
import { Trainee } from '../trainees.model';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { TraineesService } from '../../trainees.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Course } from '../../courses/courses.model';
import { CoursesService } from '../../courses.service';
import { Assignment } from '../../assignments/assignments.model';
import { traineeCourses } from '../../assignments/traineeCourses.model';
import { courseAssignments } from '../../assignments/courseAssignments.model';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AssignmentsService } from '../../assignments.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-trainee-details',
  templateUrl: './trainee-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./trainee-details.component.css']
})


export class TraineeDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public selectedDates : any = {};
  public enrolledTrainers: any = {};
  private traineeId: string;
  trainee: Trainee;
  assignments: Assignment[] = [];
  courses: Course[] = [];
  counter: number;
  traineeCourses: traineeCourses = {
    id: null,
    assignments: null,
    courses: null,
    trainee: null  };
  public isLoading = true;
  private courseSub: Subscription;
  private assignmentSub: Subscription;
  courseAssignments: courseAssignments[] = [];
  courseAssignment: courseAssignments;
  coursesdisplayColumns = ['courseOrderID', 'courseTitle','courseDescription','duration','scheduledDate','trainer','save'];
  
  constructor(public traineeService: TraineesService, public route: ActivatedRoute, public coursesService: CoursesService, public assignmentsService: AssignmentsService)
  {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      if(paramMap.has('traineeId')){
        this.traineeId = paramMap.get('traineeId');
        this.trainee = this.traineeService.getTrainee(this.traineeId);
        this.traineeCourses.trainee = this.trainee;
      }
    });
    this.getData();
  }

 async getData()
 {
  await this.coursesService.getCoursesByJob(this.trainee.job);
  await this.assignmentsService.getAssignmentsForTrainee(this.trainee.id);
  this.courseSub = await this.coursesService.getCoursesUpdateListener().subscribe((courses: Course[]) =>{
    this.courses = courses;
    this.traineeCourses.courses = this.courses
    console.log('Promise Y resolved.');
  });

  await this.assignmentsService.getAssignmentsForTrainee(this.trainee.id);
  this.assignmentSub = await  this.assignmentsService.getAssignmentUpdateListener().subscribe((assignments: Assignment[]) => {
    this.assignments = assignments;
    this.traineeCourses.assignments = this.assignments;
    this.traineeCourses.courses.forEach(element => {
      this.courseAssignment = {
        id: null,
        courseID: element.id,
        courseDescription: element.description,
        courseOrderID: element.courseOrderID,
        courseTitle: element.title,
        duration: element.duration,
        trainer: null,
        scheduledDate: null
      };
      this.traineeCourses.assignments.forEach(element => {
        if(this.courseAssignment.courseID == element.courseID)
        {
          this.courseAssignment.trainer = element.trainer;
          this.courseAssignment.scheduledDate = element.scheduledDate;
        }
      });
    this.courseAssignments.push(this.courseAssignment);
    });
    this.isLoading = false;
    console.log('Promise X resolved.');
  });
  console.log(this.courseAssignments);
 } 

  onDelete(traineeId: string)
  {
    this.traineeService.deleteTrainee(traineeId);
  }

  onSaveAssignment(trainee: Trainee, selectedCourse: Course, selectedDate: Date, enrolledTrainer: string){
  
    this.assignmentsService.addAssignment(selectedCourse.id, trainee.id, enrolledTrainer, selectedDate);
    console.log(trainee.id);
    console.log(selectedCourse.id);
    console.log(selectedDate);
    console.log(enrolledTrainer);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.assignmentSub.unsubscribe();
    this.courseSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

As you can see in the code above I am creating an object courseAssignment for each entry then I. Push each one of them into courseAssignments that I use in the HTML to cycle it in the table.

and this is my HTML code:

```html
<mat-card>
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner>
    <form  #traineeForm="ngForm" *ngIf="!isLoading">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input  readonly matInput type="text" name="name" [ngModel] = "trainee.name"  #name="ngModel">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input readonly matInput email type="text"  name="email" [ngModel] = "trainee.email" #email="ngModel">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input readonly matInput type="text"  name="type" [ngModel] = "trainee.type" #type="ngModel">
      </mat-form-field>
      <button mat-raised-button color ="primary" type ="submit">Edit</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color ="warn" type ="submit" (click)="onDelete(trainee.id)">Delete</button>
    </form>
  </mat-card>
<br>
  <mat-card *ngIf="!isLoading">
    
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="courseAssignments" class="mat-elevation-z8" >
      
      <ng-container matColumnDef="courseOrderID">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Course Order ID</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.courseOrderID}}</td>
      </ng-container>
      
       <ng-container matColumnDef="courseTitle">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Course Title </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.courseTitle}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="courseDescription">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Course Description </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.courseDescription}}</td>
       </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="duration">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Duration </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.duration}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="scheduledDate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Scheduled Date </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
         <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="selectedDates[i]" placeholder="Choose a date">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
         {{element.scheduledDate}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="trainer">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Trainer </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
              <mat-form-field><input matInput color="warn" *ngIf="!element.trainer" [(ngModel)]="enrolledTrainers[i]"></mat-form-field> {{element.trainer}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="save">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
              <button mat-raised-button color ="primary" type ="submit" (click)="onSaveAssignment(trainee, element, selectedDates[i], enrolledTrainers[i])">Save</button></td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="coursesdisplayColumns">
      </tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let courses; columns: coursesdisplayColumns"></tr>
      </table>
      <br>
 
      </mat-card>
```

---

This is the errors that start after I click on a user:

[image]

Would anyone be able to help me make the interface wait for everything to finish? I tried using async but I kind of failed to grasp on how this functions in angular.

Comment: Those errors seem to suggest that Angular can't find a form control inside mat form field, rather than data being missing. Have you considered this as a potential source of the problem yet? If not, I would consider checking that you are properly importing your material modules. I think, normally, if the issue was that data is missing, you'd see reference errors, like `Cannot read property type of undefined`.

Comment: You are actually right, i never thought this could actually be the issue.
The issue was with  `<mat-form-field>`, the input inside it had a condition `*ngIf="!element.trainer"` after looking further into it i found out that you can't use the `<mat-form-field>` without having at least an input or textbox in it so every time my If wasn't true it was crashing it.

However if anyone knows a better way to optimize the typescript it would be much appreciated, it's giving me serious issue when it's executing stuff before my APIs have time to return things.

Comment: Have you considered creating resolvers for getting the courses and assignments? If you add a resolver to a route in Angular, the resolver will load your data before the component for that route is loaded. https://codeburst.io/understanding-resolvers-in-angular-736e9db71267

Comment: Thanks, i didn't actually know about Resolvers. They look really awesome, this will simplify stuff for me.